# How to generate click event through code

Tags: selenium

How to click the buttton?  Can you suggest the code to send the click event to the 'Place Order' button shown below:

```
enter <dl class="final unpoint">
      <dt>
        <p>By clicking "Place Order", you agree to create this campaign.</p>
      </dt>
      <dd>
        <button>Place Order</button>
      </dd>
    </dl> here
```

Here was my attempt:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dd[@button = 'Place Order']")).click();
```

But, I get the following error:

> rg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//dd[@button = 'Place Order']"} (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 221 milliseconds

Comment: You should specify how you tried to resolve issue, what obstacles you have encountered, programming language that you use, your part of code for this issue, but not to ask someone to provide a code

Comment: Try using the `click()` method.

Comment: Here was my attempt: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dd[@button = 'Place Order']")).click(); but I get the following errror: rg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//dd[@button = 'Place Order']"}
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 221 milliseconds

Comment: @squathub please edit the problem description and add the code. Also, please format the code. It is hard for everyone to read code from the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Place Order')]")).click()
```